# How to launch the dialog box at the end of the game without clicking on a button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dialog

I am very new to android. I made a very basic pong game. I want to launch the dialog box when the ball is out. This code indicates that the ball is out

```
////// end game
        if (ball1.getEndGame()&&ball2.getEndGame()){
            Log.e(TAG, "END of game");
        }
```

**this is my activity:**

```
public class GameScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        View gameview = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(gameview);
    }


}
```

**this is my GameView class which is extending from the view**

```
public class GameView extends View {

    // declare variables

    private static final String TAG = null;     // for log.e

    private Ball ball1;             // ball1
    private Ball ball2;             // ball2
    private GameContainer gameContainer;        // frame for the game
    private Racket racket;              // controller
    int viewWidth = 0;              // width onchange
    int viewHeight = 0;                 // height onchange


    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int width = metrics.widthPixels;            // width of screen
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;          // height of the screen

    int rectSize = 200;                         // width of the controller
    int rectHeight = 40;                        // height of the controller

    int rectL = (width/2 - (rectSize/2));       // x 
    int rectT = height-(rectHeight*3);          // y
    int rectR  = (width/2 + (rectSize/2));      // x + rectSize
    int rectB  = rectT + rectHeight;            // y + rectHeight

    // random numbers for speed
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomNo1 = r.nextInt(20 - 3) + 3;      
    int randomNo2 = r.nextInt(20 - 3) + 3;
    int randomNo3 = r.nextInt(20 - 3) + 3;
    int randomNo4 = r.nextInt(20 - 3) + 3;


    // random numbers for location 
    int randomXLocation1 = r.nextInt((width-10) - 1) + 1;
    int randomYLocation1 = r.nextInt(height/2 - 1) + 1;
    int randomXLocation2 = r.nextInt((width-10) - 1) + 1;
    int randomYLocation2 = r.nextInt(height/2 - 1) + 1;

    // getter for speed
    float getSpeedX;
    float getSpeedY;

    // score
    private Score score;
    int currentScore = 0;


    // constructor
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        randomNo1 = randomNo1 * -1;
        randomNo2 = randomNo2 * -1;
        randomNo3 = randomNo3 * -1;
        randomNo4 = randomNo4 * -1;

        ball1 = new Ball(Color.GREEN, 24, randomNo1, randomNo2);    // colour, radius,speedx, speedy 
        ball1.setBallLocation(randomXLocation1, randomYLocation1);  // x, y of ball

        ball2 = new Ball(Color.RED, 24, randomNo3, randomNo4);      // colour, radius,speedx, speedy 
        ball2.setBallLocation(randomXLocation2, randomYLocation2);  // x, y of ball

        gameContainer = new GameContainer(Color.GRAY);
        racket = new Racket(Color.BLACK);

        score = new Score(Color.WHITE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        //randomNo1 = r.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
        //randomNo2 = r.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
        //randomNo3 = r.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;
        //randomNo4 = r.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;

        gameContainer.container(1, 2, width-2, height-3);
        gameContainer.display(canvas);



        ball1.drawBall(canvas);
        ball1.moveBall(gameContainer);
        //ball.collides(racket);
        if(ball1.collides(racket)){
            String collided = "collided Yes";
            Log.e(TAG, collided);

            getSpeedX = ball1.getBallSpeedX();
            getSpeedY = ball1.getBallSpeedY();

            getSpeedY = getSpeedY * -1;
            randomNo1 = (int) getSpeedX;
            randomNo2 = (int) getSpeedY;

            if (randomNo1 > 0) { randomNo1 += 1; }else{randomNo1 = randomNo1 + (-1); }
            if (randomNo2 > 0) { randomNo2 += 1; }else{randomNo2 = randomNo2 + (-1); }

            ball1.setBallSpeed(randomNo1, randomNo2);
            currentScore = currentScore + 1;
        }

        ball2.drawBall(canvas);
        ball2.moveBall(gameContainer);

        if(ball2.collides(racket)){
            String collided = "collided Yes";
            Log.e(TAG, collided);

            getSpeedX = ball2.getBallSpeedX();
            getSpeedY = ball2.getBallSpeedY();

            getSpeedY = getSpeedY * -1;
            randomNo3 = (int) getSpeedX;
            randomNo4 = (int) getSpeedY;

            if (randomNo3 > 0) { randomNo3 += 1; }else{randomNo3 = randomNo3 + (-1); }
            if (randomNo4 > 0) { randomNo4 += 1; }else{randomNo4 = randomNo4 + (-1); }

            ball2.setBallSpeed(randomNo3, randomNo4);
            currentScore = currentScore + 1;
        }


        //racket.setRacket((width/2)-60, height-220, (width/2)+60, height-160);
        racket.setRacket(rectL, rectT, rectR, rectB);
        racket.setLine(2, rectT+(rectHeight/2)-1, width-2, rectT+(rectHeight/2)+1);

        racket.drawRacket(canvas);
        score.drawScore(canvas, 20, 40,Integer.toString(currentScore));



        ////// end game
        if (ball1.getEndGame()&&ball2.getEndGame()){
            Log.e(TAG, "END of game");
        }


        // Delay
        try {  
           Thread.sleep(50);  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        invalidate();  // re-draw

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

```
if (ball1.getEndGame()&&ball2.getEndGame()){
    Log.e(TAG, "END of game");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); 
    builder.setMessage("End of game");
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
           //do whatever u want here
        }
    });
    AlertDialog mAlert = builder.create();
    mAlert.show();
}
```

mContext has to be your application context. Also declare the mAlert outside of the function.
you can also add other options to the builder as you want.